Is it possible to send the errors captured with ACRA by customizing the JSON body?
I need the body of the JSON that I will send to the API to report errors to have the following format:
{
   "error_message":"This is a test error message.",
   "dispo_info":{
      "REPORT_ID":"a123b456",
      "APP_VERSION_CODE":"100",
      "APP_VERSION_NAME":"1.0.0",
      "ANDROID_VERSION":"12",
      "STACK_TRACE":"java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat com.example.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)"
   }
}

The one originally sent is:
    {
      "REPORT_ID":"a123b456",
      "APP_VERSION_CODE":"100",
      "APP_VERSION_NAME":"1.0.0",
      "ANDROID_VERSION":"12",
      "STACK_TRACE":"java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat com.example.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)"
   }

Until now I know that with ACRA.getErrorReporter().putCustomData(); can i add fields.

You will probably need to implement your own Custom Report Sender
Depending on what current report sender you are using you could probably extend that class and then Override the send method in which you could re-organise the CrashReportData Object (which is just a JSONObject) and call the original send
Or depending on the current Report Sender Override the correct method to reformat the data before sending. e.g. the HTTP Sender you could override the convertToString method to report the data sent.

Thank you for your response, it was very helpful to me, I needed to register the sender and in the documentation that you shared with me (sender of custom reports) below there is another link that says to see custom extensions. And that's it, really thank you, I've been thinking about this for a while

Hey, maintainer of ACRA here. Just confirming that overriding convertToString is the intended solution to modify just the json body, and implementing a custom report sender can give you even more control if needed.

Excellent, totally grateful for the help
